# how to use JsonSlurper to get root element?

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I'm trying to understand how to receive the root element "person" from the flowing json code:

```
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText('{"person":{"name":"Guillaume","age":33,"pets":["dog","cat"]}}')

 assert result.person.name == "Guillaume"
 assert result.person.age == 33
 assert result.person.pets.size() == 2
 assert result.person.pets[0] == "dog"
 assert result.person.pets[1] == "cat"
```

I need the actual name 'person' from the response.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `result` is a `Map`, you can do:

```
assert result.keySet() == [ 'person' ]
```

Comment: @user2011376 accept and vote up instead of adding "thanks" comments.

Comment: And to extend - to get the string use  `println result.keySet().iterator().next()`

Comment: Or just, `result.keySet()[0].toString()`